# What is the purpose of a static method in interface from Java 8?

Tags: java, class, interface, java-8, static-methods

Why are static methods supported from Java 8? What is the difference between the two lines in main method in below code?

```
package sample;
public class A {
    public static void doSomething()
    {
        System.out.println("Make A do something!");
    }
}

public interface I {
    public static void doSomething()
    {
        System.out.println("Make I do something!");
    }
}

public class B {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A.doSomething(); //difference between this
        I.doSomething(); //and this
    }
}
```

As we can see above, I is not even implemented in B. What purpose would it serve to have a static method in an interface when we can write the same static method in another class and call it? Was it introduced for any other purpose than modularity. And by modularity, I mean the following:

```
public interface Singable {
    public void sing();
    public static String getDefaultScale()
    {
        return "A minor";
    }
}
```

Just to put like methods together.

Comment: That should explain it: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html

Comment: There's no difference.

Comment: Static methods provide default methods that implementing classes do not to override. Its particularly useful if the the method logic is replicated across all the implementations. Your example is useful, say classes PopSong and RockSong can implement it and both would have default scale as A minor.

Comment: @Marvin So they are used as helper methods and for modularity? How were helper methods implemented before Java 8 for the same type of functionality?

Comment: "What purpose would it serve to have a static method in an interface when we can write the same static method in another class and call it?" - well, you don't have to make a separate class now just to hold the static methods.

Comment: @Arunav Sanyal You are confusing static and default methods.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In the past, if you had an interface `Foo` and wanted to group interface-related utils or factory methods, you would need to create a separate utils class `FooUtils` and store everything there.

Those classes would not have anything in common other than the name, and additionally, the utils class would need to be made `final` and have a private constructor to forbid unwanted usage.

Now, thanks to the interface static methods, you can keep everything in one place without creating any additional classes.

It's also important to not forget all good practices and not throw everything mindlessly to one interface class - as pointed out in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45781243/2229438)

Comment: @GrzegorzPiwowarek `Collectors`, `StreamSupport`, `Spliterators` are not redundant classes at all; there has to be a line for code that is *too much* inside an interface.

Comment: @Eugene Of course, there will always be some exceptions and this is a very good example. Putting all of this into one class would result in an unmanagable mess

Answer (score 15):

There are mainly two reasons for static method inside interfaces: `create instances` of those interfaces (and the code is clearly where it has to be); like `Predicate::isEqual` that would create a `Predicate` based provided Object; or `Comparator::comparing`, etc. And the second reason would be `utility methods` that are general per all those types; like `Stream::of`

Still an interface has to be *clear* and does not have to create additional clutter in the API. Even the jdk code has `Collectors` - static factory methods, but a `Collector` interface at the same time for example. Those methods could be merged into `Collector` interface, but that would make the interface more clunky than it has to be.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the `create instances` usage? Instead of using `Stream.of`, I think we may well opt for `Arrays.stream` to create the instance. The reason for `Stream.of` over `Arrays.stream` more or less falls back to grouping related utility methods in one namespace, which is your second use case. Or did I misinterpret your example?

Comment: @wlnirvana what do you think `Stream::of` does internally?

Comment: It internally uses `Arrays.stream`. And that's exactly my point: you first reason ultimately falls back to your second reason. In this case, `Stream.of` is just a wrapper. To me, the motivation of this wrapper seems to be more "`utility methods` that are general per all those types" than "`create instances` of those interfaces".

Comment: @wlnirvana indeed. I see your point now. I've edited the answer and thank you for the input.

Comment: I see your point now as well. Thanks for the nice example.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that we can call the static method by interface name and that static method can call the default method internally. Example: Comparator::comparing, so here comparing is calling the default functionalities.

Comment: No need to repeat the question, Ashish. Try and create as formal an answer as possible, things like "ex : " are not preferred on SO. An edit has been made and will be approved soon, so no need to change the text now.

Comment: How does a static method call a default method? Can you give an example? Because otherwise this seems unclear.